# Convert ImageView to Drawable

Tags: android

I have a Bitmap in ImageView in one class called TakePicture. Image is passed by

```
public Bitmap getImage(){
        return image.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

I want to use it in Drawable in other class like

```
TakePicture picture=new TakePicture();
Drawable drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  picture.getImage());
```

it gives me this error and the activity is stopped

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{me.myProject/me.myProject.GMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at me.myProject.TakePicture.getImage(TakePicture.java:58)
at me.myProject.GMap.onCreate(GMap.java:42)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: please point us to **line 58** of the `TakePicture` class and any contingent code as well.

Comment: line 58 is
return image.getDrawingCache();

Comment: please make sure that the `image` object has been properly initialized for the method. otherwise post the class if you want us to do it for you.